# Swift with no ARC

Tags: memory-management, swift, automatic-ref-counting

Is it possible to write apps using manual memory management (instead of automatic reference counting) using SWIFT?

Can I call `retain` and `release` using Swift?

Comment: After comments in my answer below and @newacct answer, I am wondering now: do yo want to avoid ARC on *some* objects in your project, or turn ARC off for the entire project? Could make that explicit in your question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can call `retain` and `release` on `Unmanaged<T>` values. `Unmanaged` is basically object pointers that are outside of ARC management. But you would have to convert to managed pointers to interact with Cocoa APIs.

But you wouldn't want to do this unless in exceptional circumstances. And a project that isn't converted to ARC isn't such a situation.

Comment: A good reason would be when you implement a LinkedList for example. Using arc will result in crashes when storing large numbers of objects in the list. See for reference: https://forums.swift.org/t/singly-and-doubly-linked-list-collections-in-standard-library/11426

Answer (score 2):

**Note Aug 29, 2014** - My answer below is not correct, it's possible, look at @newacct answer

No you can't. Read more about [Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-XID_88).

You must have a very good reason for not wanting ARC

Comment: Ah ok. Afraid you wanted to do something strange :)

Comment: I'm working on a non-ARC project and I was wondering if I can add Swift code without turning it into an ARC project.

Comment: @godmoney - With ObjC you can mix ARC and non ARC libraries. So, I guess the answer is 'probably'.

Comment: Antonio, there are good reasons for not wanting ARC. ARC makes strong references the default in too many places. I argued that strong references is the wrong default (can link my article if you're honestly curious). Anyway my point is, you insert a debatable comment in your own answer, and like many people you seem to think that memory management automations like GC and ARC are 'almost unarguably good'.

Comment: Ok. In that case look at @newacct answer, it looks like I was wrong and it's possible to bypass ARC using `Unmanaged`. Never looked into that because it's something I would avoid at any cost :) But if you say you need it, then you can

Comment: I've worked with C and C++ a lot in the past years, and one of the most common mistakes I made was deleting objects too early or forgetting to delete. If that process can be automated it's much better for the software quality. In some cases it's needed to have more control (and I think that's your case). But all modern languages provide automatic lifecycle management. Have you taken a look at swift's `weak` and `unowned`? Maybe they can be good workarounds for what you want to achieve.

Comment: There is a very specific use case which I am requiring disabling for is if you want to primarily implement your app through C-bindings by linking with swift object files. Swift will otherwise GC object too soon so I'd want to use my host language to call the destructor when necessary

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to turn off ARC for swift in the way that you can with objc (e.g. per file with a compiler flag).  As others have pointed out there are the 'Unmanaged' and 'UnsafeMutablePointer' APIs, designed for interaction with C APIs, that allow you to work around ARC in some instances.  However these APIs are cumbersome and require you to make substantial changes to your code (e.g. for interacting with arrays).

The Swift people would generally want you to rewrite your code to use structs and avoid reference issues where possible.  But this makes porting existing code painful.

There are some suggestions in my other post regarding ARC performance here: [Swift Dictionary slow even with optimizations: doing uncessary retain/release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353299/swift-dictionary-slow-even-with-optimizations-doing-uncessary-retain-release/31621515#31621515) but none are very satisfying.

I've gone so far as to write code to post-process the compiled mach-O object code and remove the ARC swift_retain/release calls from some classes as an experiment.  But I'm really hoping that now that Swift is open sourced we can just modify it to make it more flexible in the future.