# NSMutableDictionary much slower than Java Map... why?

Tags: objective-c, performance

The following code, which maps simple value holders to an object, runs over 15x faster in Java than Objective-C using XCode 7 beta3, "Fastest, Aggressive Optimizations [-Ofast]". I can get over 280M lookups/sec in Java but only about 19M in the objc example.  (I posted the corresponding Java code here as this started as a Swift comparison: [Swift Dictionary slow even with optimizations: doing uncessary retain/release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353299/swift-dictionary-slow-even-with-optimizations-doing-uncessary-retain-release)).

This is a simplified version of my real code which is definitely bound by hash lookup time and exhibits this overall performance difference as well.  In the test below I'm testing the value for null just to make sure the compiler doesn't optimize away the lookup, but in the real app I'd be using the value in most cases.

When I look at instruments I see a lot of time spent in retain / release, msgSend, and some locking calls that I don't understand.

Any ideas on what could account for this being 10-15x slower than Java or any workarounds would be appreciated.  I can actually implement a perfect hash like the one below so I could use a fast int-object dictionary for iOS if I could find one.

```
@interface MyKey : NSObject <NSCopying>
    @property int xi;
@end

@implementation MyKey
    - (NSUInteger)hash { return self.xi; }
    - (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object    { return ((MyKey *)object).xi == self.xi; }
    - (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone { return self; }

@end

    NSMutableDictionary *map = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2501];
    NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];

    int range = 2500;
    for (int x=0; x<range; x++) {
        MyKey *key = [[MyKey alloc] init];
        key.xi=x;
        [map setObject:obj forKey:key];
    }

    MyKey *key = [[MyKey alloc] init];
    int runs = 50;
    for (int run=0; run<runs; run++)
    {
        NSDate *start = [NSDate date];

        int reps = 10000;
        for(int rep=0; rep<reps; rep++)
        {
            for (int x=0; x<range; x++) {
                key.xi=x;
                if ( [map objectForKey:key] == nil ) { NSLog(@"missing key"); }
            }
        }

        NSLog(@"rate = %f", reps*range/[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:start]);
    }
```

Comment: Using `NSNumber` in place of `MyKey` doubles performance indicating that  `MyKey` is responsible for about 1/2 of the performance. Agreed that `NSNumber` may not be the best performance test. But there is a timing problem with the the hash and equality methods as well as creating key objects for the test that are part of the timing.

Comment: I am not trying to make the point that Objective-C NSMutableDictionary is even near the speed  given for the Java implementation. But I am surprised by the difference.

Comment: You are correct that using NSNumber is faster and I don't know why. FYI, I used the mutable key to avoid any memory allocation during the read loop.

Comment: Interestingly mutable is essentially a flag. NSNumber is handled specially, if the integers fall in a certain range objects are not created, just the number is shifted and a bit set in one of the least significant bits. This can be done because addresses fall on boundaries that otherwise leave these bits 0.

Comment: I tried this: https://github.com/gianlucabertani/FastDictionary/  fast int keyed dictionary that claims to be 2.5x as fast as NSMutableDictionary but it was slower in my test.

Comment: If performance is an issue there is always the option to use C++ containers. There is such a thing as Objective-C++ (.mm extension).

Comment: Gianluca Bertani who wrote the FastDictionary mentioned that he turned off ARC in testing his code and that he validated that it is faster as he claimed.  I notice that turning off ARC makes the NSMutableDictionary test faster as well by about 2x.  But so far nothing has gotten within a factor of 2 of the Java code.

Comment: Please, add your Java code, otherwise it's really hard to judge. However, note that the first time the Java code is run, it is compiled to highly optimized native code (by JIT) so it should be very fast.

Comment: Method calls in Java are substantially faster (once JITCed) than method calls in Objective-C.

Comment: I wonder if playing around with NSMapTable instead of NSDictionary would help?

Comment: Are the locking calls because you have not declared the `xi` property as `nonatomic`? You have declared no attributes, which implicitly means that the property is `atomic`.

Answer (score 2):

You could reimplement your `-isEqual:` method like this to avoid property accessors:

```
- (BOOL) isEqual:(id)other
{
    return _xi == ((MyKey*)other)->_xi;
}
```

That would not be acceptable if your `MyKey` class might be subclassed, but I see from the Java code that the class there is `final`.

Answer (score 1):

The computational complexity of the NSMutableDictionary is the next (from CFDictionary.h file):

```
The access time for a value in the dictionary is guaranteed to be at
worst O(N) for any implementation, current and future, but will
often be O(1) (constant time). Insertion or deletion operations
will typically be constant time as well, but are O(N*N) in the
worst case in some implementations. Access of values through a key
is faster than accessing values directly (if there are any such
operations). Dictionaries will tend to use significantly more memory
than a array with the same number of values.
```

Means, almost all the time you should have O(1) complexity for access/insertion/deletion. For Java `HashMap` you should get pretty much the same.

According to [this](http://www.objc.io/issues/7-foundation/collections/#should-i-use-dictionarywithcapacity) research there are no benefits in using `dictionaryWithCapacity:` convenience initializer.

In case you use integer as a key, probably it would be possible to replace dictionary with array.

In this [WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=412) they explained `objc_msgSend` performance issues and how to deal with them.
The first solution is to use C++ and STL containers. The second one is to use Swift, because unlike Objective-C it is only dynamic when it notes to be.

Comment: This doesn't explain 1) why Java is 10x-15x faster than ObjC in this benchmark, or 2) why Swift is nearly 2x slower again.

Comment: 1) In Java you have bytecode and JVM. It is meaningless to compare Java vs. Objective C / Swift performance. 
2) The tests depends on numerous factors like implementation, compiler, optimization level, etc. According to these [benchmarks](https://github.com/vsco/swift-benchmarks) everything is ok with Swift performance.

Comment: Of course it's meaningful to compare these things. Java, despite its JIT, is reputed to be one of the slowest mainstream languages around. Both Objective C and Swift are statically compiled and have strong compile-time optimizations available. They'd be expected to destroy Java in a tight microbenchmark like this, but they don't, by an order of magnitude. Why not, and why the optimizer is letting us down so drastically, are interesting questions worthy of discussion. Your answer doesn't even scratch the surface.

Comment: It just seems to me that there is a huge inherent penalty for using ARC that the Swift designers sort of hand-wave away by suggesting that we rely on structs and value semantics.   But this makes these languages difficult to use in these high performance apps.  The "unfair" advantage that Java has here is that when working with a fixed pool of objects then referencing them is "free".  But ARC (at least currently) doesn't have a way of knowing that they are long lived and has to do all this extra unecessary work to ref count them.