# Optimize Swift Dictionary Assignment Performance

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I've been profiling my code and found that >50% of running time is spent in a line assigning a value in a Swift dictionary.

```
Running Time    Self (ms)       Symbol Name
10675.0ms   51.0%   9.0                            Swift.Dictionary.subscript.setter (A) -> B?
```

It's the second line of this fuction

```
func isConsistent<V, D>(variable: V, value: D, assignment: Dictionary<V, D>, csp: CSP<V,D>) -> Bool {
    var tempAssignment = assignment
    tempAssignment[variable] = value
```

This is one line in a medium size program (that takes non-trivial time (~80 seconds on my 1.7 ghz i7) to execute) and this particular line is not being called any more frequently than most others. How can I speed it up?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353299/swift-dictionary-slow-even-with-optimizations-doing-uncessary-retain-release

Comment: That's a year old and doesn't specifically address assignment as a concern.

Comment: It's not a year old; it's two weeks old and the original poster has just given a very useful answer.

Comment: Please don't waste bandwidth asking why you're downvoted. The downvoter is long gone and won't see your comment. It's a wisdom-of-the-crowd site. You just have to live with it.

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter felt that spending 50% of your time here (or anywhere) is not interesting. After all, you have to spend your time _somewhere_. And 50% of a very short time is a _very_ short time. So you have not even really shown there's a problem.

Comment: Okay I added a caveat. Still don't see how that question is relevant - profiler does not show the majority of my program's time being spent in retain/release.

Comment: Nevertheless you're using a dictionary (expensive because to assign by key we have to search on that key first) and a generic (expensive because we don't know whether or not to do reference counting).

Comment: Okay thanks for your insight. Surprising though given that the dictionary has very few keys (and I would assume uses a hash function to lookup the values associated with the keys) that it would be so slow.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary are value types which means it will be copied every time you assign it to another variable
Try remove the assign statement

```
    func isConsistent<V, D>(variable: V, value: D, assignment: Dictionary<V, D>, csp: CSP<V,D>) -> Bool {
        //var tempAssignment = assignment//remove this line
        assignment[variable] = value // use assignment instead
```

Comment: You can't do that assignment - remember the original dictionary "assignment" is a function parameter.

Comment: You declare the argument as `var assignment: Dictionary<V,D>` and then you can modify it.  Modify it locally; if you want the passed in dictionary to change, your need `inout`.